# How to make an INDIRECT formula but with adjusting ranges

Tags: excel-formula, excel-indirect

I'm hoping someone can help me make better use of the INDIRECT formula.

I have a list of sheet names in a table and an INDIRECT formula that uses that list to return a value in a specified cell - the list of sheet names is just an easier way for me to drag the formula down the table and read the appropriate cells without having to manually link each sheet.

=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!"&"K10")

This works fine for single cells as the range ref is simply stated as the text in the formula (K10), the problem arises when I need to start referring to a range such as K10:K15 and summing the values.

The range K10:K15 will inevitably have new rows added or deleted on the relative tab and as INDIRECT is using text as the reference it means the range doesn't automatically adjust - this is as I understand it one of the 'benefits' of INDIRECT but in this case is actually holding me back.

Also worth noting that the range (K10:K15) may move as rows are added/deleted above this, as this range is part of a larger table.

In simplistic terms I want to achieve the same result as a standard reference to a range on another sheet, e.g. =sum(sheet1!K10:K15) (as this will adjust when rows are added/deleted) but I just want to be able to dictate which sheet is referred to via a list I have in a table on a summary sheet.

How do I either write INDIRECT so the range adjusts when new rows are added/deleted or is there a different formula I should be using that achieves this?

Any advice greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K"& MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K:K")<>"",0)&":K"&MAX((INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K:K")<>"")*(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K:K")))))`

This indirectly references the rows from the first non empty cell up to the last non empty cell in given sheet in column K. Not sure if you need to enter with `ctrl + shift + enter` (not in the app version).

Note: If the range contains empty cells in between the first and last non empty cell it will be included as value 0

Or in office 365 use the following:
`=FILTER(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K:K"),INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K:K")<>"")`

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned in the question that the starting cell may move too as rows can be added above K10. Also the range K10:K15 is the second section in a larger table so there are more values in column K that I want to ignore. I will amend the question the accordingly. Thanks

Comment: In that case you need to update your question with the condition the range of column K in the dynamic sheet should meet.

Comment: There isn't really a condition as such - beyond the cell actually containing data. But the data in column K is all the same type and there is no unique identifier in column A as it's a product name. it's more about the section of the table i'm interested in, so maybe using a section header with an offset would work? I have added a bit to the question if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried the second option (it requires office 365 version of excel). This will select all non-empty cells in row K no matter where it starts/ends or no matter if it's intermitted with blank cells.

Comment: Thanks but that won't work as it will pull in every non-blank in column K, I just want the values in the range I initially specify (until it changes through the adding/deleting of rows).

Comment: It won't pull every blank. Only if there are blanks in between the first and the last value.